# How to expose and trigger onready function globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I go about exposing the following two functions below for global access? `functionWithinOnReady();` and `handleSomething();`

Within the scope of `theme` I can trigger the functions with:

```
theme.handleSomething();
theme.functionWithinOnReady();
```

Assuming I would need to trigger the functions from a third script (/globally), how would I go about this in the best way?

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var theme = {

        onReady : function(){
            functionWithinOnReady = function() {
                //want to access this globally
            }
        },
        handleSomething: function() {
            //want to access this globally
        },
        onLoad : function() { },
        onResize : function() { }
    };


    $(document).ready( theme.onReady );
    $(window).load( theme.onLoad );
    $(window).resize( theme.onResize );

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `window.theme = {`.. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/b9LLjnaL/)

Answer (score 1):

You could attach `theme` to either the window (global) or jQuery

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    $.theme = {

        onReady : function(){
            functionWithinOnReady = function() {
                //want to access this globally
            }
        },
        handleSomething: function() {
            //want to access this globally
        },
        onLoad : function() { },
        onResize : function() { }
    };


    $(document).ready( $.theme.onReady );
    $(window).load( $.theme.onLoad );
    $(window).resize( $.theme.onResize );

})(jQuery);
```

Now you can access `$.theme` anywhere, and if it's supposed to be used on jQuery collections, you could prototype it with `$.fn.theme` instead.

Comment: would this expose all functions within theme? As im only looking to expose a select few functions within theme

Comment: Yes it would, you can't pick and choose what properties of an object are exposed, it's either the entire object or nothing. If you want specific properties, use another object that reference the properties you want in `theme`

Comment: Would you have any examples of the latter or any reference to where I can check out some examples on that approach?